# Handling virtual keyboard on an EditText

Tags: android, events, virtual, keyboard-events

I'm running into trouble getting the key events on an `EditText` with the virtual keyboard.  The user is prompted to type something and i need to capture those events as they time.  I need to be able to get the `keyup` and `keydown`.  I need to get the timing of the ups and downs. this is designed for 3.1  Is there any way to get these events?  Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: what kind of trouble exactly are you running into? could you add the code that you've written where you're trying to capture the key-events?

Comment: I had this project on an old pad and had created a keyboard out of buttons to collect the ups and downs.  I now moved up to a xoom and need the full functional keyboard.  I was trying using a onkey for this, but as far as i know i can't capture a keyup on a virtual with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) says

> A key press starts with a key event with ACTION_DOWN. If the key is
>   held sufficiently long that it repeats, then the initial down is
>   followed additional key events with ACTION_DOWN and a non-zero value
>   for getRepeatCount(). The last key event is a ACTION_UP for the key
>   up. If the key press is canceled, the key up event will have the
>   FLAG_CANCELED flag set.

Please, try something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    etField =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text);

    etField.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
             // register the text when "enter" is pressed
             if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
             || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
             int timesPressed = event.getRepeatCount();
             //do something
        }
    });
}
```